# Changing smoothing factors in perls chart::gnuplot module

Tags: perl, gnuplot, rrdtool

In perls Chart::gnuplot (or the interactive terminal version of gnuplot as a second best), when applying smoothing is there a way of varying the 'tightness' of changes of direction of the plot?

I hope this is not a bad explanation of what I am getting at. Im not highly mathematical and I don't really understand the mathematical basis of smoothing graph curves. I am just trying to get some graphs of network traffic originating in netflow packets captured from cisco devices. I can see that rrdtool makes nice graphs which look natural and intuitive to the eye but I have not been able to replicate the look in Chart::gnuplot (I don't want to use rrdtool because the application does not really fit the tool - it would be a hack - I just want to spit the PNG files out of the current perl application which collects and sorts the data from various cisco devices around the network).

If I use csplines with a dataset of 50 x coords I just get a graph of jagged edges. With 5 x coords I get a nice smooth graph but its 'oversmoothed' - not what I need. If I were to try to describe it I would say I am after something which looks more like a histogram (or to be more precise in gnuplot terms I mean style=boxes) but with a degree of 'flow' to it. A good example would be http://oss.oetiker.ch/rrdtool/gallery/btdmd8.png.

If anyone can comment thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Well I never found a way to do it. So I used Chart::Clicker instead which gets the effect I want somehow. It leaks memory though :-( only significant because I am writing a thousand graphs in one execution of the program.